# Why is a matrix invertible when its row-echelon form has no zero row?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If the row echelon form of a square matrix has no zero row, it is invertible. Otherwise, it is singular.

Why?

If the row echelon form has a zero row, in a linear system, it has either no solution or infinitely many solutions. So, is invertibility linked to having only one solution?

Is there a **geometrical** interpretation for my question?

Comment: A zero-row in the row echelon form means that the (square) matrix has not full rank. A square matrix with size $n\times n$ is invertible if and only if its rank is full (rank=$n$)

Comment: @Peter Hi Peter. I have not learned ranks yet. I am looking for an answer that involves geometry or solution sets, if it is possible.

Comment: Geometrical interpretation : If a square matrix with size $n\times n$ has full rank , then the row vectors as well as the column vectors form a basis. They span the full $\mathbb R_n$. For $n=2$ and $n=3$ this can be visualized.

Comment: Hi i dont know if i can link vidoes but this one does give a pretty good intuitive understanding .https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQhTuRlWMxw

Answer (score 5):

Excellent. Your request for a **geometric interpretation** shows me that you are on the right track in learning linear algebra! (Well, at least visualizing the standard 1-3 dimensions)

Consider the Reduced Row Echelon Form (**RREF**) of a matrix `A`, it concisely describes some of the **subspace** information associated with `A`.

The **RREF** tell us:

- **rank** : *number of basis vectors in the column space/range*
- **nullity** : *number of basis vectors in the null space/kernel*
- **Invertibility/Linear independence** : *Whether the null space is trivial or not*

The null space being trivial (i.e, consisting of only an **appropriate** null vector) implies that the column space of `A` occupies the entirety of it's dimension(equal to the column count of A) and that there is no linear combination of any vectors in it's range that reduce to 0 vector.

The process of matrix inversion is supposed to find a subspace which when multiplied with `A` gets projected to the **appropriate** identity matrix.

If there is any linear combination of columns of `A` that reduces to 0, then it cannot be reversed to map onto it's original linear combination, which means that the vector is nullified. (Mapped to the **0 vector**). This is exactly what the **rank** of a matrix succinctly describes with mathematical beauty.

> **So, such linear vector combinations of non-invertible matrices are consumed by it's null space/kernel!**

The exact same can be witnessed and verified on the column space and null space of the non-invertible matrix `A'` (which are incidentally, **NOT coincidentally**, the row space and left-null space of `A`)

Answer (score 0):

Just think about the [Gauss-Jordan method of finding the inverse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). To find the inverse of a matrix $A$, that is , $A^{-1}$, we write the augmented matrix $[A; I]$ where $I$ is the unit matrix of the same order as $A$.

Just think what will happen when $\det A =0$. The elementary row operations performed produce one or more rows of zero at the bottom so that $A $ cannot be reduced to $I_n $. In fact, in this case, $A $ reduces to its normal form $\begin {bmatrix} I_r & 0\\ 0 & 0\end {bmatrix} $ since rank$_A  < n $.

Hope it helps.